# Extracting a number of files from very large tar.gz

Tags: bash, tar

I have a conundrum of having to extract 20,000 files from a tar.gz that contains 4 million files without extracting the entire archive due to limited disk space. I have a list of 20,000 file names, and can do, in principle,

`tar zxvf archive.tar.gz myfilename1`

20,000 times, but even doing this takes too long. Is there a good solution for this?

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If an answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey ☑ to the left of the text, which means "yes, this is THE answer"!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`man tar`

```
  -T, --files-from FILE
           get names to extract or create from FILE
```